# Controll the Cell Spacing from another cell GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

what i want is to make the first textField more near the First jlabel, and some space between the first textfield and the Second jlabel, like this:

JLABEL: JTEXTFIELD ----(spaceeee)----------JLABEL: JTEXTFIELD

but everything i change do not get near what i want, look:

[image]

my code that add the TFields and the Jlabels:

```
    JLabel lblProtocolo = new JLabel("Protocolo:");
    JLabel lblDataEntrada = new JLabel("Data Entrada:");
    JTextField tfProtocolo = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField tfDataEntrada = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField soteste = new JTextField(10);
    JLabel soocupa = new JLabel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    panel2DistribuidorDistribuir.add(lblProtocolo,gbc);
gbc.gridx = 1;
    panel2DistribuidorDistribuir.add(tfProtocolo,gbc);

gbc.gridx = 2;
    panel2DistribuidorDistribuir.add(lblDataEntrada,gbc);

gbc.gridx = 3;
    panel2DistribuidorDistribuir.add(tfDataEntrada,gbc);
```

i know that if a add some invisible jtextfield in the gridx = 4; and then set the weight once time for this new jtextfield to =1 and the others to 0, it will "WORK" BUT the components in gridx = 0,1,2,3 will not be auto resizable anymore =(, any clue guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gbc.weightx = 1;` is basically saying the component wants to occupy 100% of available space.

What I would do is start by removing it...

You could also play around with `gbc.insets` to effect the distance between the individual components...

Take a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

**Update with example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GridBagLayoutTest100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GridBagLayoutTest100();
    }

    public GridBagLayoutTest100() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JLabel lblProtocolo = new JLabel("Protocolo:");
            JLabel lblDataEntrada = new JLabel("Data Entrada:");
            JTextField tfProtocolo = new JTextField(10);
            JTextField tfDataEntrada = new JTextField(10);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            add(lblProtocolo, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            add(tfProtocolo, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(lblDataEntrada, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            add(tfDataEntrada, gbc);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: impossible, if i remove the gbc.weightx = 1; everything go to the CENTER, and not resizable.... how would you suggest for the gbc.insets, because insets has more effect when i add everything in the same gridx and gridy and than i set the space of each element, but this will be a lot of work if i have a lot of components

Comment: but i was using shared constraints, buttt

I resolved it simple adding weightx = 0; for JLabels and Weightx = 1; for the TextFields, i dont know if this is the better, but worked

Comment: You mean something like the example?

Answer (score 1):

Add your components to GridBagLayout having set GridBagConstraints. You can define insets when defining the GridBagConstraints.A sample code is as below

```
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 155, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{94, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        setLayout(gridBagLayout);



        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textArea.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 15);
        gbc_textArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_textArea.gridx = 2;
        gbc_textArea.gridy = 0;
        add(textArea, gbc_textArea);
```

Comment: thanks the answer, but just worked for the First JLabel, First TextField, Second JLabel, the last JTextField only he expand and have a distance from the Second JLabel =(

Answer (score 0):

It's late but i post this trick, it works like you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JLabel lblProtocolo = new JLabel("Protocolo:");
    JLabel lblDataEntrada = new JLabel("Data Entrada:");
    JTextField tfProtocolo = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField tfDataEntrada = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField soteste = new JTextField(10);

    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    f.getContentPane().add(lblProtocolo,c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    f.getContentPane().add(tfProtocolo,c);

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    c.gridx = 4;
    f.getContentPane().add(tfDataEntrada,c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.weightx = 1;
    lblDataEntrada.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    f.getContentPane().add(lblDataEntrada,c);


    f.pack();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Example:
[image]